# recvmsg return error(EBADF) when communicate between two processes using socketpair?

Tags: android, linux, sockets, ipc

I'm developing a program which do IPC's call between two processes.I create two socket fd using **socketpair**:

```
int fds[2] = {-1,-1};
if (socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds)) {
    return NULL;
}
```

In process A(with **system** permission), I send an integer(handle) by **send** (using fd[0]) function:

```
int sock_send_all(int sock_fd, const uint8_t* buf, int len) {  
    int s = len;
    int ret = send(sock_fd, buf, s, 0);
    ...
}
```

In Process B(with user permission), it wait to receive the handle by **recvmsg** (using fd[1]):

```
ret = recvmsg(fd, &msg, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

problem occurs in here: the recvmsg immediately return -1 with **errorno** equals 9(EBADF)!

I have surfed web a long time to try to find the answer but no any helpful information. Do you have any hints or suggestions? Thanks!

Is this an issue about process privilege level? or I should use **setsockopt** to set something?

Comment: How did process B get hold of `fd[1]?`

Comment: @EJP: I actually develops my program on Android platform. The process B is a client process of IBinder(Android IPC machanism). To put it simply, fd[1] is received through another unix-socket(I think Android use unix-socket to implement IBinder driver in kernel)

Comment: I confirm that the values of fd[0] and fd[1] before calling **send** and **recvmsg** are the same as the values returned from **socketpair**.

Comment: Please show the code used to send and receive the file descriptor.  Also, for the privilege concern you could test the code in an unprivileged case.  And are you sure your allegedly "system permission" app really has it?  Just declaring it in the Manifest will not make it so.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem.
The key point is to encapsulate the raw file descriptor into **ParcelFileDescriptor** object and transfer the object to another process, rather than transfer the file descriptor directly between two processes.
I think the implementation of **ParcelFileDescriptor** in android does some configurations about the raw file descriptor. Maybe I should read the implementation code to find the real reason of that.
Thanks all of u!

Comment: I had the same issue, and this is my solution as well.

The ParcelFileDescriptor must be transferred interprocess as its parcel, and then re-serialized into a ParcelFileDescriptor once it arrives into the other process. Passing the raw int ParcelFileDescriptor.fd value will not suffice. Unix/Android likely assigns different int fd values per process, that point to the same underlying pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something about IBinder that I don't know, handles in one process aren't valid in another process. Why can't you keep using the original socket?

Comment: I am porting some existing code in Android, rewriting is a long-time and boring job:)

Comment: This exchange doesn't make much sense.  First, like unix domain socketss, Binder can do "magic" to pass usable file descriptors, but there's no evidence of such being done in the code of the question.  And the comment in response makes no sense as it argues against re-writing, while Binder would only be a factor if the non-Android code were rewritten to make use of Binder instead of unix sockets...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agreed. The whole thing doesn't make sense to me.